# Use mod to calculate which row was tapped in?

Tags: javascript, grid-layout, modulo

This is more of a math problem really. I have a 3 column grid and am trying to determine which row a tap was in.

I just can't quite work out the math so that a tap of item 0,1,2 will output 0 and a tap of 3,4,6 will output a 1 etc. Any ideas for how to do this calculation?

```
Row0 = items 0, 1, 2
Row1 = items 3, 4, 5
Row2 = items 6, 7 ,8
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just looking for division, not modulus or remainder:

```
var row = Math.floor(x / 3);
```

Example:

```js
var i, row;
for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
  row = Math.floor(i / 3);
  console.log(i + " => " + row);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: @FuegoDeBassi: We've all been there. :-)

Comment: I tried this but wasn't rounding it and was like "this isn't right" ... but yea, with that round down, works perfect